# How do I assign a button to close the dialog?

Tags: android, xml, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have a dialog with my own markup:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_menu, null);
    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textMenu);
    btnOk = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    btnCancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    title.setText(R.string.end_game);
    text.setText(R.string.end_text);
    btnOk.setText(R.string.btnOk);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCancel.setText(R.string.btnCancel);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    if (id == DIALOG_EXIT) {
        title.setText(R.string.main_menu);
        text.setText(R.string.menu_text);
        adb.setView(view);
        return adb.create();
    }
    if (id == DIALOG_END){
        title.setText(R.string.end_game);
        text.setText(R.string.end_text);
        adb.setView(view);
        return adb.create();
    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}
```

How can I close the dialog box when I click the button "btnCancel"? The method finish() in this case does not work correctly.

Comment: show the part of the code where u initialize this dialog

Comment: And how to initialize it? I'm just calling a method showDialog(...);

Comment: Thanks, I found: dialog = adb.create();

Comment: now u can dismiss it by dialog.dismiss();

Comment: I use dismissDialog(DIALOG_END); or dismissDialog(DIALOG_EXIT);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.dismiss();
```

the method finish is for activities.
and >>**this**<< here is the instance of Dialogue (for your problem inside dialogue class).

and if you want to finish an activity from Dialogue you need to pass activity instance to dialogue class.

Comment: I'm just calling the method showDialog(...);  And how to initialize the dialog? What should be included as a parameter in parentheses: dialog = new AlertDialog(...);

Comment: When I write this: "dialog = new AlertDialog(this);" I have an inscription: AlertDialog (android.content.Context) 'has protected access in' android.app.AlertDialog

Comment: Thank you, I found: dialog = adb.create();